# Свойства объектов JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты

Свойства объекта можно получить таким образом:
`obj['property']`.
Но что если свойства нужно получить из строки (например `'pink.floyd.songs'`), мы делаем `split('.')` и получаем что-то вроде:
`obj['pink']['floyd']['songs']`.
Проблема состоит в том, что мы преждевременно не знаем, сколько будет вложений (строка могла быть, к примеру, такой: `'elbow.songs'`). Каким образом можно работать со свойствами объектов в этом случае? Необходимо не просто получить значение некоторого св-ва, но и присвоить ему некоторое значение. Т.е. получаем на вход некую строку, разбиваем ее на массив названий свойств, нужно получить что-то вроде этого: `obj['prop1']['prop2']['prop...'] = someValue`.
На основе ответа создал функцию для своей задачи, может кому пригодится:

```
function props(obj, arr) {
    var result = obj;
    for (var c = 0, l = arr.length; c < l - 1; c++) {
        result = result[arr[c]];
    }
    return {obj: result, prop: arr[arr.length - 1]};
}
var o = props(obj, props);
o.obj[o.prop] = 'Some Value';
```

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#get

Comment: я уверен на 100% уже был такой вопрос

Comment: Не очень понятна проблема. С такой формулировкой могу предположить вычислять размер массива.

Comment: Свое решение нужно оформить в виде ответа

Comment: `o.obj[o.prop] = 'Some Value';` - я б внутрь отправил. А так, вроде в вопросе уже и ответ есть. В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: ну сначала то не было. Я ответил на свой вопрос благадоря ответу kff.

Answer (score 3):

Что может быть проще?

```
var obj = ...;
var names = "...".split(".");
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i)
    obj = obj[names[i]];
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: тадам :-) обновление вопроса: теперь надо еще и значения присваивать :-)

Answer (score 1):

Вот мое решение на основании ответа @kff:

```
function objProps(obj, arr) {
  var result = obj;
  for (var c = 0, l = arr.length; c < l - 1; c++) {
      result = result[arr[c]];
  }
  return {obj: result, prop: arr[arr.length - 1]};
}
var o = objProps(obj, props);
o.obj[o.prop] = 'Some Value';
```